# Timestamp of attachment in Australia time in apex

Tags: apex, datetime, timezone

I am generating a CSV and the name consists of the timestamp 
 attachCSV.Name = salesOrder.name + ' ' + System.Now()+'.csv';

Its taking US time presently but the required time should be current time in (GMT+10:00) Australian Eastern Standard Time.

Adding a snippet of the same.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to format date in Australia time or based current user timezone?

Comment: Format date in australia time zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert current DateTime into Australia time zone DateTime

```
DateTime currenttime = DateTime.now();
String strConvertedDate = currenttime.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'Australia/Sydney');
system.debug('----Australia Time--'+strConvertedDate);
```

You can find all the timeZone keys here http://www.salesforceben.com/list-timezonesidkey-salesforce/